# Canvas create an image from URL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a url that generates images on canvas with parameters. I works ok when I load with browser.

The last line is:

```
 window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

When I try to use this url from another page like:

```
<img src="http://localhost/index.html?i=0 />
```

Doesnt load. How can i load it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security issue.  You can't read image data in canvas if the image is not on the same domain.  There aren't any work-arounds, sorry

Comment: if they are in the same domain http://example.com/index.html?i=0 i can embed it like <img src="http://example.com/index.html?i=0" />

Comment: Are you generating images using pure canvas methods (lines, shapes, etc?) or by using `getImageData()` to load other images?

Comment: put it into a jsFiddle or add your data to the question.